# Dojo 1.6 Custom Build Error - invalid propery id

Tags: javascript, dojo, custom-build

I'm trying to use a dojo custom build for my app and set up a standard profile for it. When I run the build.sh I get this:

```
(...)
release:      ../../release/dojo/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.html
release:  Optimizing (shrinksafe) file: ../../release/dojo/dojo/k11CustomDojo.js
js: line 42106: invalid property id

js:         this.loadingPane = dojo.create("div", {class:"chart-preloader"}, this.containerNode, "last");
js: .........................................^
```

It seems to complain about the `dojo.create()` call!? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` is a reserved word in javascript.

Put `class` in quotes

```
this.loadingPane = 
  dojo.create("div", {"class":"chart-preloader"}, this.containerNode, "last");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/twbfs/